# How to fix localStream is null issue using Quick Blox

Tags: webrtc, quickblox

I am implementing `quick blox video chat`. Facing issue with audio getting following error,

> TypeError: this.localStream is null for both video and audio.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A code sample would be appreciated.

Comment: And please ask a question rather than just stating a problem.